# ruby on rails redirect_to parameter passage not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My controller file looks like this:

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @popup = params[:popup]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @popup.present?
        format.html { render layout: false }
      else
        format.html
      end
      format.json { render json: @quote }
    end
  end

  def create    
    @quote = Quote.new(params[:quote])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.save
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: "Quote was successfully created.", popup: "1" }
        format.json { render json: @quote, status: :created, location: @quote }
      else
        format.html { render action: "errors", layout: false }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

If I visit http://localhost:3000/quotes/1?popup=1 -- the view correctly displays without application_layout

However, if I am coming from the CREATE action, it seems ?popup=1 is never being appended to the URL - and therefore the application_layout is displaying when it should not be

I thought that adding popup: "1" to the redirect_to line was supposed to pass a param via GET

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: tried this on my machine and it worked:

`{ redirect_to quote_path(@quote, :popup => "1"), notice: "Quote was successfully created." }`

Comment: No errors but still did not pass the param, I'm using Rails 3.2 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try `@quote_url(:popup=>1)` I guess it will work.